# How to set up parameter in hector_localization stack to fuse IMU and Barometer (Pressure sensor)?

Tags: ros, sensor-fusion, imu

Im checking the [hector_localization](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_localization) stack, that provide the full 6DOF pose of a robot or platform. It uses various sensor sources, which are fused using an Extended Kalman filter. Acceleration and angular rates from an inertial measurement unit (IMU) serve as primary measurements and also support barometric pressure sensors. I check the launch which is this one

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node pkg="hector_pose_estimation" type="pose_estimation" name="hector_pose_estimation" />
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="hector_pose_estimation_rviz" args="-d $(find hector_pose_estimation)/rviz_cfg/hector_pose_estimation.rviz" />
</launch>
```

But can not find the way hot to set up the `hector_pose_estimation` node and the launch file to get IMU and Pressure (barometer) data as input. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to remap the input topics hector is expecting to the topics you're systems are outputting. Check [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_pose_estimation?distro=noetic) for a full list of topics and params. In the end your launch file should look something like this. Note you need to put in your own topic names.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node pkg="hector_pose_estimation" type="pose_estimation" name="hector_pose_estimation">
    <remap from="raw_imu" to="/your_imu_topic" />
    <remap from="pressure_height" to="/your_barometric_topic" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="hector_pose_estimation_rviz" args="-d $(find hector_pose_estimation)/rviz_cfg/hector_pose_estimation.rviz" />
</launch>
```

Comment: great , thanks will check. the link you provide is about rosbag. Can not see anything about topics and parameters. Please can you check the link again?

Comment: @Bob9710 That's my fault, I was answering a `rosbag` question at the same time. The link is correct now.

Comment: yes. now ok. Thanks

Comment: I got this error wnen using this launch file `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node pkg="hector_pose_estimation" type="pose_estimation" name="hector_pose_estimation">
    <remap from="raw_imu" to="/rexrov2/imu" />
    <remap from="pressure_height" to="/rexrov2/pressure" />
  </node>
</launch>` The error i got is ` Client [/hector_pose_estimation] wants topic /rexrov2/pressure to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/PointStamped/c63aecb41bfdfd6b7e1fac37c7cbe7bf], but our version has [sensor_msgs/FluidPressure`  So hot to use with my Pressure sensor?

Comment: I fix the Pressure problem but now the TF is not correct. How to fuse imu data to tf and z value on /height topic in hector_pose_estimation? I open a  new question. Please can you check?